# Auto spacing in Firefox search bar does not work

Tags: keyboard, firefox-for-android

As the title says, the auto spacing feature does not work in Firefox search bar. 
This issue seems to be related only with that bar, because auto spacing works fine
in forms or text fields in web pages and it works in the other apps too. 
My Android version: 4.4.2
I hope somebody else has already experienced this problem.

Comment: What keyboard are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177216).  It seems like it was introduced with 4.2.2.  Downgrading to before that is not a *good* option, but might be available to you.

It affects multiple browsers with multiple keyboards, so I assume the issue must be with the specific type of text field used for their address bars.  I used to encounter this with Chrome but haven't lately, so you could also try that browser instead of Firefox.  In the thread above, someone also mentioned that the stock Google keyboard did not cause the issue for them.

Comment: This isn't a bug, this is by design. The application, in this case the browser, sets input type hint for the URL bar to be text box for entering a URL, and the keyboard switches to URL keyboard, which provides helper keys like a `.com` key and disables autospace since URLs usually don't have spaces. If you have a relatively recent device, use the Home Button Search (by default this is usually to Google Now or S-Voice, but can be customized to launch Firefox Search).

Answer (score 0):

as @MatthewRead says, this is a known bug. Here are some more details:
Apparently, for some reason the phone thinks that browsers are only for typing web addresses. Since URLs don't have spaces, the phone disables auto space by default. This make sense since many browsers use the same box for both searching and the URL, but often causes inconveniences. The only possible solution is to either go to your search engines website, or looking for and trying other browsers.